# Vanishing integral in deriving stress-energy tensor from action

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, cosmology, cosmological-inflation

In the derivation of the energy-stress tensor for a scalar field (context: Inflation Theory for Cosmology) by varying the action with respect to the metric, the integral over spacetime that is included in the definition of the action just "magically disappears". Why is this? My variational calculus knowledge isn't that good so the problem may lay there.

I have a link which shows the mentioned derivation:
[Derivation Energy-Stress Tensor from action S](http://hep.itp.tuwien.ac.at/~wrasetm/files/2017S-GRplusScalar.pdf)

To to go from (1) to (4) you vary the action, which includes an integral over spacetime. Why does this integral disappear is my question? I suppose it is because of the variation with respect to the metric, but the integral is over spacetime so I don't really get the 'why'.

Comment: When asking about context of a paper/book/website/etc, please copy the relevant passage and give specific details what you don't understand (see [this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11144/25301) for more details). Otherwise we can only guess at what you don't understand.

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Please consider to make question self-contained, mention author, title of link, so it is possible to reconstruct the question in case of link rot.

Comment: The link in the question is a pdf of one page, where in the calculation of the energy-stress tensor (calculations for equation (4) ) in the first line you vary the action S. If you look at equation (1) you see an integral over spacetime in the action. Why does this disappear when you vary the action with respect to the metric, is my question? I thought I specified clearly, my excuses.

Comment: It may be that you explained it will, but the fact is you are still relying on people downloading that document. Just copy the relevant portion of the text into the post as they previous two comments suggested.